# make a break line on data text

Tags: php

I get text data from a database.  I want to make a line break if there is a dash or a full stop.  How can do it?

Here is the code that I have.

```
function text_format($txt) {
  echo str_replace(array('-','.',':'), "<br/>", $txt);
 }
```

This code insert break-linse, but the characters will be deleted, what I need is to insert break-lines without deleting characters

Comment: can you correct this code ?

Comment: You have an extra closing parenthesis on your `echo` line. Having error reporting turned on would have alerted you to this.

Comment: @SimonBerra Because someone comments doesn't mean they were the one to vote up or down. If you changed something, indicate **that you changed something** instead of demanding that someone removes a downvote.

Comment: @SimonBerra: I don't understand why your question was closed as being unclear. (Maybe it was closed because you didn't include code that did exactly what you wanted.) One quick solution to the problem is just one small modification to your existing code. For the replacement value (second argument in the call to str_replace), use an array rather than a single string, each element of the array corresponding to an element in the search array (first argument); in each element of the array INCLUDE the character being searched for, so replace e.g. **`:`** with **`:<br/>`**, so colon char remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try

```
function text_format($txt) {
if (!empty($txt)) {
    $find = array('-',',');
    $replace = array("\n","\n");
    echo str_replace($find, $replace, $txt));
  }
 }
```

Comment: it's not insert a break line it's remove the caracters

Comment: @SimonBerra This solution does solve your problem though if you dare to [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Find out what this code does, then adjust it so it does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix is to provide an array as a second argument:

```
str_replace( array('-','.',':'), array('-<br/>','.<br/>',':<br/>'), $txt);
                    ^   ^   ^           ^        ^        ^
```

Each element in the replace array corresponds with an element in the search array; note that the elements in the replace array contain the character you don't want removed.

Answer (score -1):

You would not need regular expressions here as it is a single task to do.
Just do the following.

```
function text_format($txt) {
    echo str_replace(array('-','.'), "\n", $txt);
}
```

The function `str_replace()` can replace special characters by others. The first parameter is a list of all the characters that need to be replaced, so here the `-` and the `.` and the second parameter is a line-break character to tell the characters that you want to replace to be replaced by a line-break.

**EDIT:** Your original code was right, is it just that you have made **two typoes**, see the comments.

Comment: missed a `\n'` there?

Comment: Indeed, fixed it. I had misread the question, I changed it into \n

Comment: Now you just have the original code

Comment: Well I have tested my answer and it does what the user exactly wanted.

Comment: Indeed it does (work as intended). OP simply has a typo  (facepalm)

Comment: No the original code has a typo in the str_replace() line and does not output anything.

Comment: Well my bad, there was another typo on line 5 ^^

Comment: This causes the empty result `$str = $text;` instead of `$str = $txt;`

Comment: it's not insert a break line it's remove the caracters

Comment: Well this does what you asked for :)